# asp.net mvc3 Image edit gets overwritten if no image uploaded on Edit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, file

I have developed an asp.net MVC3 application. Once a record is being edited, and if there are no images on edit that we want to upload, the existing image is getting overwritten. Any idea on how to avoid this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PaymentSchedule paymentschedule, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {

            paymentschedule.ReceiptImage = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            paymentschedule.ReceiptImageType = file.ContentType;
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            paymentschedule.ReceiptImage = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
        }
        db.Entry(paymentschedule).State = EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {                db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            foreach (var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0} failed validation\n", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());
                foreach (var error in failure.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }
            }

            throw new DbEntityValidationException(
                "Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:\n" +
                sb.ToString(), ex
                ); // Add the original exception as the innerException
        }
        return RedirectToAction("SearchCust");
    }
    return View(paymentschedule);
}
```

The view to edit is a normal submit. Any idea?

Here is code for Edit view:

```
@model fbpm.Models.PaymentSchedule

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Payment Schedule";
}

<h2>Edit Payment Schedule</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "PaymentSchedule", FormMethod.Post, new
            {
                enctype = "multipart/form-data"
                , id = "parentForm"
            })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment Schedule</legend>
        <div style="float:left; width:400px">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ScheduleID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ScheduleID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleText)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScheduleText)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleText)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ScheduleDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleDate)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="Save Payment Schedule" />
        </p>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width:400px">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SchedulePercentage)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SchedulePercentage)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchedulePercentage)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleAmount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScheduleAmount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleAmount)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RemainingAmount)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RemainingAmount)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RemainingAmount)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RemainingAmount)
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width:400px">
        <div class="editor-field">
        <img src='/fbpm/fbpm/PaymentSchedule/GetImage/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ScheduleID)' width="300" height="300" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReceiptImage)
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReceiptImage)
        </div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReceiptImageType) 
             <input id="file" title="Upload a Receipt Image" type="file" name="file" />
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "SearchCust")
</div>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would need to double check your view code, but it looks like the file input for the upload is probably called **ReceiptImage** - if so that will be reset on the submit when MVC does its Model update magic. AFAIK the file upload doesn't need to be the field name of the image, try setting the Id of the file input control to something different and see if it overwrites the value still.

Comment: You mean, just rename the id "file" to say "file1"? And change this in both view and the controller?

Comment: Ok, I think the reason why its getting overwritten is the @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReceiptImage) control added on to the page. ReceiptImage looks like a blob field which wont be rendered properly by in the hidden field. But that field will be posted back to the server and will then overwrite whatever the original value was. Take the hidden field out and it should stop overwriting when editing the other values.  Its what I said in my original answer, just a different field that is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and made sure that file == null when you have not selected a file? You might need to check the ContentLength also.  I usually have this in my code: if (file!= null && file.ContentLength > 0).

Comment: The best part here is that, the current code works fine in the local system. But, the image is getting overwritten ONLY when it is run in the server..